# How would one go about digitizing/backing up original xbox game disks to pc or external hard drive?

Tags: xbox

Greetings Stack Exchange! I had been digitizing my physical video game library until I hit a snag in copying my original xbox games. It was easy enough to create iso files from PS1 and PS2 disks. When an original Xbox game is inserted into my pc drive however, the drive only reads a paltry amount of data (~13-14 Mb). Being comparable to a PS2 game, as they are from the same console generation, the game disk should have at least 1-4 Gb of data. I found this article (http://www.biline.ca/xbox-copy.htm) that informed about original Xbox copy protections and advises workarounds but it is a rather old article and I am wondering whether things have not simplified somewhat. Most contemperary articles I could find on the web concern Xbox 360 and Xbox1. There are articles about modding the original xbox console but, if possible, I would prefer to sidestep hard ware and play from an emulator going forward. Is it currently straight forward to back up original xbox games or will I have to to modding and FTP? Thank you for your time and consideration.

Comment: personally I would simply hit the web...you can find plenty of sites iut there that will host these for you and eliminates the risk of a bad rip due to damage to your disks....that said I would look into apps designed to rip the copies specifficaly for the xbox...I believe I have seen a number of them though cant be sure which ones I may have used but many are free....alcohol, isoburner...maybe even deamontools....

Comment: I've never tried to backup my games before, but this seems like a pretty clear question. Not sure why it's in the close votes queue.

Answer (score 1):

If using an original Xbox is out of the question,
due to your not wanting to FTP the files,
the dump doesn't "feel" as if dumped in full as you are only dumping the game data portion, not the security and DVD video portion.
Or your original Xbox is dead or lost.

Then using a special DVD drive is your only option, due to eluded security Microsoft has implemented.
There are 2 types:

- Kreon drive (this is (often) a retail normal PC DVD drive with special "Kreon" firmware.
- A 0800 Xbox360 SATA drive (with custom firmware)

Follow http://wiki.redump.org/index.php?title=Microsoft_Xbox_and_Xbox_360_Dumping_Guide to make a legal full dump. This site does NOT offer any of the listed games but does offer you to compare your dumps to their known dumps, so be sure to have accurately dumped your games.

Once you have dumped your games to redump quality, you sadly cannot play these games nor you can burn them to play in your original Xbox/Xbox360.
For the modded original Xbox and modded 360, you need to extract the game files and rebuild an ISO ready for burning. It will get rid of the security and the modded Xbox will not check for this security (that would be broken anyway due to media checks failing, your burned disk will never be a pressed disk).

Use XDVDMulleter (Beta 10.2) to extract the redump ISO into an ISO that you can either burn or let Xemu/Xqemu read (Xbox emulators). Xbox_Image_Browse_v2.9.0.350  might also work.

> The benefit to the more complex/expensive 0800 method is that it can
> read the security sector info properly from the "XGD3" type of Xbox
> 360 discs. [Microsoft Xbox and Xbox 360 Dumping Guide](http://wiki.redump.org/index.php?title=Microsoft_Xbox_and_Xbox_360_Dumping_Guide#Two_Hardware_Setups_to_Dumping)

If you also want to dump your 360 collection. Overall, for simply emulation, I'd really go for a modded Xbox and FTP the files over. Fast, and you know if the disk works. Once modded, it's region free anyway.

Answer (score -2):

I believe there are speciffic apps and such you can download for most of the original xbox games (I believe some had special disks) nero, alchohol110% ,imgburn,and daemon tools come to mind...search for the console name iso ripper ( International Standards Organisation)

for the newer consoles ie 360 I understand you need to either buy a special drive or possibly attach your sata  disk drive from your console to your pc(not sure if this works) most speciffically liteon and certain samsung models I have heard work.

as commented by others it is far easier to download the backups and as long as you have a reliable connection and source you dont have to worry about read errors from a scratched disk...
despite many peoples thoughts it is not illegal to download a digital copy aka backup of software you own legal rights to as you are not breaking any copyright laws. PIRACY IS A CRIME as any idiot who has read the disclaimer at the start of a dvd knows,and cannot be supported. I have heard claims that if you are transfering the data through a torrent it is openly seeded and you become responsible for the fact that you may be illegally distributing software to others and hence is advised against. The sites hosting the content typically being open to distribute to anyone without question do run substantial risk of facing legal repercussions for the content they host. some content also may fall under the category of abandoned work products and copyrights do expire as microsoft no longer manufactures nor sells original xbox content and you cannot turn to them to demand a replacement disk and the condition of your own are unknown.This does not perclude you from facing searches by cops,if a warrant were issued and to defend against these events I would strongly advise you never dispose of your physical copy,if nothing else is viable at a minimum I would keep a binder filled with your cover art from the outside of the case to prove original ownership; BUT NEVER DOWNLOAD WHAT YOU DONT OWN THE RIGHTS TO.

There are contentions to the application of the law but blacks law dictionary which every us court accepts for refferance defines the word own to include the mere act of holding,hence this may be part of the reason many games are locked up in stores as they are more expensive than movies traditionally. But the letter of the law on copyright infringement requires you to ***illegaly*** make copies or distribute...as a legal owner of rights to a digital backup of software you have legally purchased the state would be required to prove you did not own the content.

Comment: Your last paragraph is also illegal and not something we can support.

Comment: Still illegal. **Downloading something you do not own the copyright for is still illegal.** Whether you own it or not is irrelevant.

Comment: @Frank the original final paragraph was not illegal as worded but in order to clarify why and provide unnecessary full disclosure I have added to it.

Comment: It's still wrong. That's not how copyright works.

Comment: you should recheck your laws there. I have spent 3years as a paralegal and have done speciffic research on this matter intensively so I can assure you it is true.

Comment: Okay. Where? If in the States, where SE resides, I sincerely doubt it. If elsewhere, US law is what matters.

Comment: If you're a paralegal, you should be able to source the applicable laws without issue. Point us at it, and I'll withdraw my dissent.